# Is it possible to reference a field variable from .ui.xml initialized in constructor?

Tags: java, gwt

I am trying to pass a paramter to a composite's (`registrationViewer`) constructor via UiBinder/ui.xml.

My `View.ui.xml` looks like this:

```
    ...
    <ui:with field='registration' type='com.example.dto.RegistrationDTO'/>
    ...
    <composites:RegistrationViewer ui:field="registrationViewer" registration="{registration}"/>
    ...
```

My `View.java` looks like this:

```
    ...
    @UiField @Ignore public RegistrationDTO registration;
    @UiField RegistrationViewer registrationViewer;

    public View(RegistrationDTO registration) {
        this.registration = registration;
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
```

My `RegistrationViewer.java`:

```
    private final RegistrationDTO registration;

    @UiConstructor
    public RegistrationViewer(RegistrationDTO registration) {
        this.registration = registration;
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }
```

However, all the fields of `registration` parameter are null in `RegistrationViewer` constructor. It seems like GWT doesn't pick up the correct instance of `RegistrationDTO` and tries to create a new instance of it.

My question is: what I am trying to do - is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@UiField` has a `provided` property whose default value is `false`, meaning that UiBinder will create an instance and assign it to the field. If you provide a value yourself, then set it to true:

```
@UiField(provided = true) RegistrationDTO registration;
```

(btw, as you're setting it from the constructor, I'd go as far as making the field `final`)